# Angular SSR on shared hosting,

Tags: node.js, angular, shared

I was following along this awesome tutorial about compiling your Angular project with Angular SSR. https://blog.daudr.me/painless-angular-ssr/. It said it is possible to run it on a Shared Webhosting. What I found out is that it isn't generating the html directly in the source. However locally it is working fine.

Is it possible that the webhosting needs a Node Express framework to make this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The webhosting does not need the *Express framework* but it needs to have *nodejs* installed, yes.

You can achieve similar results (when it comes to SEO) with using the [App shell](https://angular.io/guide/app-shell). Since this is done during build time, you do not need any special requirements for the server you are hosting the app on.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, would you suggest to delete my files I've generated during the tutorial? And only use the app shell?

Comment: Oww and do you if it is possible to let angular generate an sitemap.xml or rss feed with dynamic content which ofcourse coming from an api?

Comment: Well that really depends on your requirements. If Angular Universal is really necessary, then you should probably change to a hosting where that works. If App shell is enough, then I would just use App shell.
For the other question please use google and if you have a concrete new question ask in a new question here on SO